# Add text to jQuery Slideshow / Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, carousel

I really like **Demo#3** on this page: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm

However I'd like to place text at the foot of each 'set' of slides.

So, **Panels 1 to 3** would have custom text saying "this is just the first set" and then when you click the disc shape (for **Panels 3 to 5**) this text would be replaced by "and this is another set".

How easy is this to achieve? To change a custom text area for each click of the slider.

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Get a better slider: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/06/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: Fair comment :) But the example posted is pretty close to what I need it to do. The others on the tripwire site are a little overkill. I need the pagination discs in the footer, 1 caption per transition & the widths of the items in the slider will be variable.

Comment: There are *hundreds* of sliders. Not kidding. I made one myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think closest (easiest) answer is this:
http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/

however you can also achieve that with
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager3.html

with a little more coding you can use simple:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Many thanks for the first link, vonsko. If I wanted to add some text below for each 'slide' on this version: http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/variable-visible-variable-size.php would this be easy to achieve?

Comment: create structure like this and it should be what are you looking for
    `<div id="carousel">  
        <div class="somePan">three elements with caption</div>  
        <div class="somePan">two elements</div>  
    </div>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Back in a tick.

Comment: Hi vonsko, running this script(http://jsfiddle.net/Z5J5J/) locally works for me however I'm a little stuck where to place the div elements you mention above. Can you show me how to? Really appreciate the help.